# Listview delete or hide some of items without error

Tags: android, listview

`ListView` delete or hide some of items , below is my code I want to hide some items in list view basically by position I or any easy way.

What I want either hide or remove whichever easy , I do not want make changes at any-other place. Please suggest easiest way to do without any error:

My code is below

```
public class sAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    private List listData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List splitData;

    public int getCount()
    {
        return listData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        return listData.get(i);
    }

    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return (long)i;
    }

    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup)
    {
        View view1;
        if(splitData.contains(listData.get(i)))
        {
            view1 = mInflater.inflate(0x7f030017, null);
        } else
        {
            view1 = mInflater.inflate(0x7f030018, null);
        }
        ((TextView)view1.findViewById(0x7f0900cc)).setText(((Map)listData.get(i)).get("itemTitle").toString());
        ((TextView)view1.findViewById(0x7f0900ce)).setText(((Map)listData.get(i)).get("value").toString());
        ((TextView)view1.findViewById(0x7f0900cd)).setText(((Map)listData.get(i)).get("unit").toString());
        ((ImageView)view1.findViewById(0x7f0900cb)).setImageResource(((Integer)((Map)listData.get(i)).get("imagehead")).intValue());
        return view1;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(int i)
    {
        if(splitData.contains(listData.get(i)))
        {
            return false;
        } else
        {
            return super.isEnabled(i);
        }
    }

    public sAdapter(Context context, List list1, List list2)
    {
        super();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        listData = list1;
        splitData = list2;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you tried?? plz explain ur prob clearly??

Comment: if i understand right, you want to hide textview or imageview. you can make it  like "textview.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);"

Comment: @prabhakaran my list views show diff list like a,b,c,d,e   i want to hide or remove b,d from list then how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

you can add a method like this on your adapter:

public class sAdapter extends BaseAdapter
  {

```
private List listData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List splitData;

public int getCount()
{
    return listData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int i)
{
    return listData.get(i);
}

public long getItemId(int i)
{
    return (long)i;
}

public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup)
{
    View view1;
    if(splitData.contains(listData.get(i)))
    {
        view1 = mInflater.inflate(0x7f030017, null);
    } else
    {
        view1 = mInflater.inflate(0x7f030018, null);
    }
    ((TextView)view1.findViewById(0x7f0900cc)).setText(((Map)listData.get(i)).get("itemTitle").toString());
    ((TextView)view1.findViewById(0x7f0900ce)).setText(((Map)listData.get(i)).get("value").toString());
    ((TextView)view1.findViewById(0x7f0900cd)).setText(((Map)listData.get(i)).get("unit").toString());
    ((ImageView)view1.findViewById(0x7f0900cb)).setImageResource(((Integer)((Map)listData.get(i)).get("imagehead")).intValue());
    return view1;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int i)
{
    if(splitData.contains(listData.get(i)))
    {
        return false;
    } else
    {
        return super.isEnabled(i);
    }
}

public sAdapter(Context context, List list1, List list2)
{
    super();
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    listData = list1;
    splitData = list2;
}


public void removeItem(int position) {
    listData.remove(position);
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

}

then in the listener where you want to trigger the action to remove the item just do this:

```
yourAdapter.removeItem(position);
```

"position" is the position of the item you want to remove